# Apple Maps, title/label overriding lat and log

Tags: ios, cordova, maps

The question is how to launch apple maps with lat/long and a title on the pin.

I have tried

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=39.40633,-74.54469(Egg Harbor)
```

But it seems that ios maps just ignores the lat/long and puts a pin on the location of the Label.
So it puts the pin in the middle of Egg Harbor Township, and not the lat/long location.

How can you on IOS put a pin on a lat/long location and label it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't possible, using q= just do a search on the maps, that's why it puts the pin in the middle of Egg Harbor, you can't really control the title of the pin

Here you can read the available parameters you can use for the urls, but there is no parameter for pins

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: Ok thanks,  I thought it would work the same as the geo: for android that allows you to put a label with geo://?lat,long (label)

Answer (score 0):

You can use q for a label of your pin IF you are supplying either an address or lat,lng.

```
ll=[lat, lng]
address=[your valid address]
```

You can do this:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=My+Custom+Label&ll=25.826816,-80.156504
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html